# iPhone not responding to Scapy arp packets

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, scapy, arp

I have built a simple network discovery tool with scapy. However I ran into an issue. The tool will find the iPhone once and then if I try to scan the network again it wont be there although the iPhone is still online and watching some youtube video. It will find every other device on the network.

I have also built a simple tool which using arp gets the mac address of an ip. That does not seem to work either. I have tried doing that with multiple iPhones and it seems that it does not work with any of them.

Here is the function that gets a mac address from the ip. I just send this arp to every ip in user defined range. And if the result is not none add it to the found devices list.

```
def mac_getter(IP, tio):
    ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')/ARP(pdst=IP), timeout=tio,inter=0.2, verbose=0)
    sys.stdout.write("Trying {0}          \r".format(ip))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    for send, receive in ans:
        return receive.sprintf(r"%Ether.src%")
```

I know that the local ip of the iPhone is 192.168.1.88 however it is not listed in the found devices. I have also tried scanning the network with netdiscover and it does find the iPhone.

Comment: iPhone tend to reject ARP packets, as a prevention against ARP poisoning from gratuitous ARP (especially gratuitous things). They typically only listen for them when logging in a wifi.